# Why does indexOf() choose to return a -1 rather than null?

Tags: javascript

I mean this more conceptually, not what part of the `indexOf()` algorithm specifically does it.

In my mind, if I were to search for a word in a string;

```
var foo = bar.indexOf("fizz");

if (foo) {...}
```

Would only be possible if `null` is returned from `indexOf()`. However, in order for the above code to work, I would have to write;

```
var foo = bar.indexOf("fizz");

if (foo !== -1) {...}
```

I can't see any advantage to returning a `-1` rather than `null`. Could somebody give me an example where it would be more beneficial?

Comment: Consider for a moment that `foo` can be 0.

Comment: Because this function returns an integer (the index) and not a boolean value. A function can not return two different types (not even in JavaScript)

Comment: @michaPau, `null`is not a `Boolean`

Comment: @michaPau JS is not typed, so a function can return anything, even another function. Consider `function(bool) { return bool ? 1 : 'a'}`

Comment: It returns an index, and semantically an index has to be an Integer

Comment: @Rayon yes over read the question nm..

Comment: an interesting consideration is `!!~(-1)` will return false , while no other integer will return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element exist in index 0, your `if (foo)` wouldn't pass although there is a result, so you cannot use that anyway.

As to why it returns `-1`, it is probably to match other typed languages behavior. This way, it will always return an `integer`.

Comment: Yes I completely forgot `if (0)`. So you're saying as for Javascript, it's just convention to match typed languages?

Comment: @PejmanPoh yes, it is a common convention. You have the same in Java or C#. JavaScript was not designed to go mainstream and had to be learned fast, so they kept familiar conventions.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is like asking why `substring()` doesn't return a `boolean`.

Semantically, index has to be an `integer`, so it doesn't make sense returning `null` where your method-name suggests that it should return an number.

Also, if it returns a `null`, they it will be equivalent to a `0` (since both are falsey values) leading some innocent/unintentional errors from developers, so there is hardly a gain in returning a null from this method.